# T430 i5 overheating

Tags: 14.10, cpu, thinkpad, overheating, temperature

## Heavy overheating - How to stop?

I have a ThinkPad T430 running a Intel® Core™ i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz × 4 (IvyBridge) on Ubuntu 14.10.

I reinstalled Ubuntu a few weeks ago. While I always thought that my notebook is getting hotter than I like, I noticed it to be **very hot on very low cpu load**. Below you'll find a detailed description of this behaviour.

I may have a hardware issue here. But as the CPU **does not get as hot on Windows** (between 55 and 70 °C, usually), there has to be a misconfiguration on Ubuntu. What could lead to this obviously bad CPU control?

### The behaviour

The below screenshots were taken with PSensors. The temperature of my two physical cores are *gray* (Scaling on the left). CPU load is *yellow*, fan speed is *violet*. **Note that the fan speed and CPU load curves are relative!** That means the highest point has the value of the repective maximum value listed below, the lowest point has the value of the respective minimum listed below. So the fan speed seams to be higher in the first picture than in the following, while it never got as low as in the first picture ever again.

One graph are always ten minutes of time passed. The first three screenshots overlap a little.

#### First ten minutes after boot

Only listening to music through Nuvola Player, not using the PC. Notice how temperature increases and increases while the CPU load is always quite low. At the end it reaches **103°C** ! Maximum value for this processor is 105°C…
[image: First ten minutes after boot. The CPU was not cooled down before boot.]

#### kidle_inject kicks in

Still only listening to music. As the CPU almost reaches its maximum temperature. `kidle_inject` kicks in at **1** to force the CPU to cool down. *Note that any additional CPU load is exclusively due to `kidle_inject`!*

At **2**, `kidle_inject` injects more than 70% idle time per core! The systems starts to freeze from time to time and gets very hard to use.
[image: kidle_inject kicks in]

#### Further development

I started using firefox to write this questions additionally to listen to music.

**3** `kidle_inject` leaves. The CPU rapidly heats up again.
**4** not much more than 2 minutes later, `kidle_inject` has to slow the CPU down again, as it already reached temperatures as high as 102°C again.
**5** `kidle_inject` leaves again. But not for long.
[image: Temperature goes up and down]

#### And so on…

Some 15 minutes later
[image]

Another 20 minutes later. `kidle_injects` now constantly injects idle time.
[image]

### TLP

I use TLP. Here's the output of `tlp-stat`:

```
--- TLP 0.7 --------------------------------------------

+++ Configured Settings: /etc/default/tlp
TLP_ENABLE=1
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_AC=0
DISK_IDLE_SECS_ON_BAT=2
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_AC=15
MAX_LOST_WORK_SECS_ON_BAT=60
CPU_MIN_PERF_ON_AC=0
CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_AC=100
CPU_MIN_PERF_ON_BAT=0
CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_BAT=70
CPU_BOOST_ON_AC=1
CPU_BOOST_ON_BAT=0
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_AC=0
SCHED_POWERSAVE_ON_BAT=1
NMI_WATCHDOG=0
ENER0GY_PERF_POLICY_ON_AC=performance
ENERGY_PERF_POLICY_ON_BAT=powersave
DISK_DEVICES="sda sdb"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_AC="254 254"
DISK_APM_LEVEL_ON_BAT="128 128"
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_AC=max_performance
SATA_LINKPWR_ON_BAT=min_power
PCIE_ASPM_ON_AC=performance
PCIE_ASPM_ON_BAT=powersave
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_AC=high
RADEON_POWER_PROFILE_ON_BAT=low
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_AC=performance
RADEON_DPM_STATE_ON_BAT=battery
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_AC=auto
RADEON_DPM_PERF_LEVEL_ON_BAT=auto
WIFI_PWR_ON_AC=1
WIFI_PWR_ON_BAT=1
WOL_DISABLE=Y
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_AC=0
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_ON_BAT=1
SOUND_POWER_SAVE_CONTROLLER=Y
BAY_POWEROFF_ON_BAT=1
BAY_DEVICE="sr0"
RUNTIME_PM_ON_AC=on
RUNTIME_PM_ON_BAT=auto
RUNTIME_PM_ALL=1
RUNTIME_PM_DRIVER_BLACKLIST="radeon nouveau"
USB_AUTOSUSPEND=1
USB_DRIVER_BLACKLIST="usbhid"
USB_BLACKLIST_WWAN=1
DEVICES_TO_ENABLE_ON_STARTUP="wifi wwan"

+++ System Info
System         = LENOVO ThinkPad T430 2349D15
BIOS           = G1ETA7WW (2.67 )
Release        = Ubuntu 14.10
Kernel         = 3.16.0-31-generic x86_64
/proc/cmdline  = BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-31-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=11551b6e-b22d-49fc-a853-9bbc0bd06294 ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
Init system    = upstart

+++ System Status
TLP power save = enabled
power source   = ac

+++ Processor
CPU Model      = Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1200000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  1320000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1200000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu1/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  1320000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1200000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu2/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  1320000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_driver    = intel_pstate
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_governor  = powersave
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_min_freq  =  1200000 [kHz]
/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu3/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq  =  1320000 [kHz]

/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/min_perf_pct      = 36
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct      = 0
/sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo          = 1

x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu0                            = performance
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu1                            = performance
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu2                            = performance
x86_energy_perf_policy.cpu3                            = performance

/proc/sys/kernel/nmi_watchdog                          = 0

+++ Undervolting
PHC kernel not available.

+++ Temperatures
CPU temp               =    84 [°C]
/proc/acpi/ibm/fan     =  4562 [/min]

+++ File System
/proc/sys/vm/laptop_mode               =     0
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_writeback_centisecs =  1500
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_expire_centisecs    =  1500
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio               =    20
/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio    =    10
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/age_buffer_centisecs  = (not available)
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/xfssyncd_centisecs    = (not available)
/proc/sys/fs/xfs/xfsbufd_centisecs     = (not available)

+++ Storage Devices
/dev/sda:
          Model     = SAMSUNG SSD 830 Series                  
          Firmware  = CXM03B1Q
          APM Level = none/disabled
          Status    = active/idle
          TRIM      = supported
          Scheduler = deadline

        SMART info:
            5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct     =        0 
            9 Power_On_Hours            =     5066 [h]
          177 Wear_Leveling_Count       =       96 [%]
          179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot     =        0 
          190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel   =       44 [°C]
          241 Total_LBAs_Written        =    6.501 [TB]


+++ SATA Aggressive Link Power Management
/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host1/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host2/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host3/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host4/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance
/sys/class/scsi_host/host5/link_power_management_policy  = max_performance

+++ PCIe Active State Power Management
/sys/module/pcie_aspm/parameters/policy = default (using bios preferences)

+++ Intel Graphics
/sys/module/i915/parameters/powersave        =  1 (enabled)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_rc6       =  3 (enabled + deep)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/enable_fbc       = -1 (use per-chip default)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/lvds_downclock   =  0 (disabled)
/sys/module/i915/parameters/semaphores       = -1 (use per-chip default)

+++ Wireless
bluetooth = off (software)
wifi      = on
wwan      = on

wlan0(iwlwifi)      : connected, power management = off
wwan0(cdc_mbim)     : not connected

+++ Audio
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save            = 0
/sys/module/snd_hda_intel/parameters/power_save_controller = N

+++ Docks and Device Bays
/sys/devices/platform/dock.0: battery_bay   = no battery 
/sys/devices/platform/dock.1: ata_bay       = no drive (or powered off)

+++ Runtime Power Management
device classes   = all
device blacklist = (not configured)
driver blacklist = radeon nouveau

/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:00.0/power/control = on   (0x060000, Host bridge, ivb_uncore)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:02.0/power/control = on   (0x030000, VGA compatible controller, i915)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:14.0/power/control = on   (0x0c0330, USB controller, xhci_hcd)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.0/power/control = on   (0x078000, Communication controller, mei_me)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:16.3/power/control = on   (0x070002, Serial controller, serial)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:19.0/power/control = on   (0x020000, Ethernet controller, e1000e)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1a.0/power/control = on   (0x0c0320, USB controller, ehci-pci)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1b.0/power/control = on   (0x040300, Audio device, snd_hda_intel)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.0/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.1/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.2/power/control = on   (0x060400, PCI bridge, pcieport)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1d.0/power/control = on   (0x0c0320, USB controller, ehci-pci)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.0/power/control = on   (0x060100, ISA bridge, lpc_ich)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.2/power/control = on   (0x010601, SATA controller, ahci)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/power/control = on   (0x0c0500, SMBus, no driver)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:02:00.0/power/control = on   (0x088001, System peripheral, sdhci-pci)
/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:03:00.0/power/control = on   (0x028000, Network controller, iwlwifi)

+++ USB
autosuspend        = enabled
device whitelist   = (not configured)
device blacklist   = (not configured)
driver blacklist   = usbhid
wwan blacklist     = enabled (cdc_acm cdc_wdm cdc_ether hso qcserial sierra)

Bus 002 Device 007 ID 046a:0023 control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Cherry GmbH CyMotion Master Linux Keyboard G230 (usbhid)
Bus 002 Device 006 ID 17ef:100a control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Lenovo ThinkPad Mini Dock Plus Series 3 (hub)
Bus 002 Device 002 ID 8087:0024 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub (hub)
Bus 002 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 001 Device 006 ID 5986:02d5 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Acer, Inc  (uvcvideo)
Bus 001 Device 004 ID 147e:2020 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Upek TouchChip Fingerprint Coprocessor (WBF advanced mode) (no driver)
Bus 001 Device 003 ID 17ef:1003 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Lenovo Integrated Smart Card Reader (no driver)
Bus 001 Device 002 ID 8087:0024 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub (hub)
Bus 001 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 004 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0003 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub (hub)
Bus 003 Device 003 ID 0bdb:1926 control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Ericsson Business Mobile Networks BV  (cdc_acm, cdc_wdm, cdc_mbim)
Bus 003 Device 002 ID 046d:c52b control = on,   autosuspend_delay_ms =  2000 -- Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver (usbhid)
Bus 003 Device 001 ID 1d6b:0002 control = auto, autosuspend_delay_ms =     0 -- Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub (hub)

+++ ThinkPad Extended Battery Functions
tp-smapi   = inactive (kernel module 'tp_smapi' load error)
tpacpi-bat = active

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT0 (Main / Internal)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = LGC
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = 45N1011
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  86580 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  82390 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  82350 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =      0 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Unknown

tpacpi-bat.BAT0.startThreshold                              =     96 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.stopThreshold                               =    100 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.forceDischarge                              =      0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend trying thermald which has been available in the past few releases of Ubuntu.    If it is not already installed, try:

```
sudo apt-get install thermald
```

By default it will try and identify ways to do passive thermal cooling, however one can tweak a configuration file to tune the cooling rules if you so desire. See: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues for more details.